# How to get property from json result

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have a JSON result witch is this, it holds only one array:

```
{
  id: "5", 
  client: "8", 
}
id: 5
client: 8
```

I'm accessing it by doing this function:

```
getClient(url: string){
  this.clientService.client(this.clientUrl).subscribe((info: ClientInfo[]) => {
    console.log(info);
    console.log(info[0].id);
  });
}
```

Where .client I'm getting it like this:

```
public client(url: string): Observable<ClientInfo[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<ClientInfo[]>(url);
}
```

The Array:

```
export class ClientInfo{
   id: number;
   client: number;
}
```

I'm having an error of 'cannot get id of undefined', is there any way to get the id of this array, since its a single array? Bdw I tried info.id but it doesn't let me access it.

Comment: I don't see an array anywhere in this code.  Since you haven't shown how `info` is defined, nor what information is output when you call `console.log(info)`, it's hard for me to imagine how to advise.  Consider adding a [mcve] as mentioned in [ask] so that others can see the issue for themselves and give you a targeted answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Could you develop a bit more your JSON ?
As far as I know, I see an object with 2 properties and no array in sight.

Comment: Sorry let me edit it and put the array..

Comment: @PierreR-A, that my result JSON which I'm viewing from the browser, since it not hardcoded

Comment: Where are you trying to access your object ?
Is it inside your function, or outside ? Your object might not be defined yet and thus cannot access the first item of your array.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Is that property undefined? Are you sure `((info: ClientInfo[]) => {....}` is actually returning an array?  Did you log in the output from that function?  It looks like you just have an object above.

Comment: @PierreR-A, I'm accessing it in a function inside a .subscribe, and it is defined

Comment: @tlm, this is the error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Could you give the function by any chance (relevant bits) ?

Comment: Could you share more of your code instead of fragments? Let the code tell the story instead of having everyone guess. It'll help us help you more.

Comment: @MexicoBoy.  It sounds like your `info[0]` is undefined.  That error means that there is no property `id` at the 0th element of `info`.

Comment: Edited it, hope it clearer

Comment: It seems you receive `ClientInfo` instead of `ClientInfo[]`
What is the output of `console.log(info.length)`?

Comment: Yes, it kind off, could it be because I'm having a single result ?

Comment: @PierreR-A undefined...

Comment: Ok, your result is not an array. You have to check your backend to see what it sends in case of single object.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a different answer from your backend when there is one result instead of several.

You can in the meantime access your object like this :

```
const item: ClientInfo = info.length ? item[0] : item;
```

This will ensure to get the first result or the only result.

Answer (score 0):

To access the info in your example, you would just use `info.id` and get the value.

If the data is in fact in an array, you could use your option. The input would have to look like this:

```
let infoArray = [
  {
    id: "5", 
    client: "8" 
  }
];
infoArray[0].id;   // "5"
```